Sed command listing all lines between pattern including the final line
I have a file similar to below.
[object_category=file]
filesystem = enabled
[object_category=registry]
registry = enabled
[privilege_id=SeAuditPrivilege]
audit = enabled
[privilege_id=SeSecurityPrivilege]
audit = enabled
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled
[shell=%2Fbin%2Fbash]
interactive = enabled
[shell=%2Fbin%2Fsh]

I am trying to pattern match so that my output has only the following lines:
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled

The command that I am using is
sed -n '/\[selinux=disabled\]/,/\[/p'  myfilename

but the output that the command provides is as below
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled
[shell=%2Fbin%2Fbash]

I don't want the last line, i.e., [shell=%2Fbin%2Fbash]. 
But somehow the SED command is capturing that line as well. 
What will be the simplest option to list only the content that I require,
i.e., like below?
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled


You can search for the first line and then scope a series a commands from there; basically print it, read in the next line, print it, quit.
% sed -n '/\[selinux=disabled\]/ {p;n;p;q}'  y
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled


note, this won't work if there are multiple lines under [selinux=disabled] before the next [shell=...], as it simply prints the one single line following [selinux=disabled] then quits. (it's unclear if that's a requirement or not.)

Remove all lines that do not match the bracketed heading with /RE/!d.  If a line matches the heading, output it and read the next line with n.  The extra line that is read will be outputted by the default output.
$ sed -e '/\[selinux=disabled\]/!d' -e 'n' file  
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled

If you have to care about duplicated matches of the regular expression (and want only handle the first match), then change the second expression from n to n;q (or add -e 'q' as a separate expression).

If the section may contain more than a single line, then you already have a good command that extracts these.  You need to remove the last line that it outputs.  Do this with another sed invocation.  There is no need to make it more complicated.
$ sed -n '/\[selinux=disabled\]/,/\[/p' file | sed '$ { /^\[/d; }' 
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled
hello

The added sed command will remove the last line if it starts with a [.

+1 for the second example, which works for multiple entries under the section heading (including zero entries). Interesting perhaps to note (for academic reasons) that the first example is the logical inverse to the accepted answer, since sed -n ... means don't print matched lines by default, except when instructed via the print (p) command, can usually be re-written as sed .... to print matched lines by default, except when instructed not to (d).  I think the second example will make more sense to most people already at least vaguely familiar with sed.

Is there only one line in the section? Then grep could do it, e.g.:
grep -FA1 '[selinux=disabled]' infile

Output:
[selinux=disabled]
insecure = enabled


If just one line follow the one you need:
sed '/[[]selinux=disabled[]]/{n;q};d' test

If more then one lines follow [selinux=disabled] section:
sed '/[[]selinux=disabled[]]/{:1 n;/^[[]/!b1};d' test

